# Microsoft Word 2007 - move text to beginning of next page shortcut

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I'm currently using Microsoft Word 2007, and was wondering if there was a keyboard shortcut to move a block of text or anything after the blinking cursor to the beginning of the next page?

This occurrs a lot, especially when I'm writing reports, etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ctrl-Return inserts a page break, which moves all text after the cursor to the next page.

Comment: appreciate it, Paperflyer!